# Pass global variables to Spring + Apache Tiles

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles, tiles2, apache-tiles

I'm currently running a working Spring + Apache Tiles webapp.
I need to show some example code to explain my intention.

Apache Tiles Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/www_base.jsp" />

    <definition name="home" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Example Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {
    @RequestMapping("/index.html")
    public String index(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("hello", "world");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

This would display `www_base.jsp` with `home.jsp` as `body`. I can use variable `${hello}` in `www_base.jsp` as well as in `home.jsp`.

But I don't want to set `hello` in each Controller method to be able to use it in `www_base.jsp` on each page.

Is there a way to set global variables for `www_base.jsp`, e.g. in the constructor of `ExampleController`?

**UPDATE**
Example Code using a Map

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BlogController {
    @ModelAttribute
    public void addGlobalAttr( Map<String, Object> map ) {
        map.put("fooone", "foo1");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index.html")
    public String posts(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("foothree", "foo3");
        return "posts";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [method annotated with @ModelAttribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods):

> An @ModelAttribute on a method indicates the purpose of that method is
>   to add one or more model attributes. Such methods support the same
>   argument types as @RequestMapping methods but cannot be mapped
>   directly to requests. Instead @ModelAttribute methods in a controller
>   are invoked before @RequestMapping methods, within the same
>   controller.
>
> @ModelAttribute methods are used to populate the model with commonly
>   needed attributes for example to fill a drop-down with states or with
>   pet types, or to retrieve a command object like Account in order to
>   use it to represent the data on an HTML form.